# Table of dynamic and static content?

Tags: nodes

With Drupal and views you can generate a table with for example a list of users and their contact details.

Let's say I have a user outside of the system that I want to add to the table statically, what's the best way to do this in Drupal?

The ways I am thinking of are:

Write a module that db_select or use enityfieldquery into an array, add the external user info and put it through theme table and outputs it on a page.

Override the views template and add the user info there.

Are there better ways?

Comment: I would experiment with the following functions using the devel moudle and dpm() function to output the variables. https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low level way is to use [`hook_query_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) - with it, you can add [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) with anything.

More **direct Views way** is [`hook_views_post_execute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7):

> This hook is called right after the execute process. The query has been executed, but the `pre_render()` phase has not yet happened for handlers.
>
> Adding output to the view can be accomplished by placing text on `$view->attachment_before` and `$view->attachment_after`. Altering the content can be achieved by editing the items of `$view->result`.